# I have one issue on implementing RecyclerView with horizontal and vertical scrolling

Tags: android

I want to implement RecyclerView with horizontal and vertical scrolling and one button on vertical item so when I clicked on button that text should be changed into save to Saved. In my app when I clicked on button, text is changed but when I scrolling down automatically another button's text is changed. Below is my code.

[In this screenshot I clicked on VerticalList3's button and text is changed successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UdTj.png)

[When I scrolled down automatically VerticalList20 and VerticalList14's button text is changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9AFD.png)

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView vertical_recycler_view,horizontal_recycler_view;
private ArrayList<String> horizontalList,verticalList;
private HorizontalAdapter horizontalAdapter;
private  VerticalAdapter verticalAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    vertical_recycler_view= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.vertical_recycler_view);
    horizontal_recycler_view= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_recycler_view);



    horizontalList=new ArrayList<>();
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 1");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 2");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 3");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 4");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 5");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 6");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 7");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 8");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 9");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 10");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 11");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 12");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 13");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 14");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 15");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 16");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 17");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 18");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 19");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 20");


    verticalList=new ArrayList<>();
    verticalList.add("verticallist 1");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 2");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 3");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 4");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 5");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 6");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 7");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 8");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 9");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 10");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 11");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 12");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 13");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 14");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 15");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 16");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 17");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 18");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 19");
    verticalList.add("verticallist 20");

    horizontalAdapter=new HorizontalAdapter(horizontalList);
          verticalAdapter=new VerticalAdapter(verticalList);


    LinearLayoutManager verticalLayoutmanager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 
LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    vertical_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(verticalLayoutmanager);
//        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
//        vertical_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer
            = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    horizontal_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);

    vertical_recycler_view.setAdapter(verticalAdapter);
    horizontal_recycler_view.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);
}



public class HorizontalAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<String> horizontalList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView txtView;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            txtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        }
    }


    public HorizontalAdapter(List<String> horizontalList) {
        this.horizontalList = horizontalList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.horizontal_item_view, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.txtView.setText(horizontalList.get(position));
        holder.txtView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,holder.txtView.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return horizontalList.size();
    }
}



public class VerticalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VerticalAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<String> verticalList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView txtView;
        public Button button;
        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            txtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
            button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.verticalButton);
        }
    }


    public VerticalAdapter(List<String> verticalList) {
        this.verticalList = verticalList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.vertical_item_view, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.button.setText("Saved");
            }
        });
        holder.txtView.setText(verticalList.get(position));
        holder.txtView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,holder.txtView.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return verticalList.size();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Potapov Anton is right but you can also do this way.

Implement this method:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This solution is very bad because each item is recreate when scrolling instead of reuse existing items. If list have more elements this solution will not work.

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView reuses viewHolder for other items. So setting text only directly to button (like this `holder.button.setText("Saved");`) in viewHolder is wrong. You need to set text to your list for an item on this position.

Comment: I am new in android can you explain whatever you are saying.

Comment: Check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: I din understand.

Comment: RecyclerView creates only several instances of ViewHolder to show on the screen and then reuses them. That's why when you set your data directly to the button it's shown on the other items

Comment: So what should I do to resolve that issue? please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You have to store state of the button too. You can create another list:

```
List<Boolean> buttonsStatus = new ArrayList<>(numOfElements);
```

and fill list:

```
for(int i = 0; i<numOfElements; i++)
{
     buttonsStatus.add(false)
}
```

or you can modify your current list to store `Item` objects like this:

```
public class Item{
     public String text
     public boolean saved;
     public Item(String text, boolean saved)
     {
          this.text = text;
          this.saved= saved;
     }
}
```

and use it in your code:

```
List<Item> verticalList = new ArrayList<>();
verticalList.add(new Item("verticallist 1", false));
...
```

and in `onBindViewHolder` method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.button.setText("Saved");
            verticalList.get(position).saved = true;
        }
    });
    Item item = verticalList.get(position);
    holder.button.setText(item.saved ? "Saved" : "Save");
    holder.txtView.setText(item.text);
    holder.txtView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,holder.txtView.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have edited my code but there is some error like java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
                                                                              at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)

Comment: if you use first solution you have to fill list by elements. I prefer second solution.

Comment: I have done my code and thanks for you to giving a time for my code.